# Note taking software that filters & displays full-length notes in individual cells much like filterable chapters PDF viewer?

Tags: note-taking, tags

I searched high low for a note taking software that can display notes at full length without truncating, in separate cells, back to back in a scrollable view. I have not yet found such option.

I understand the difficulty of having such design but my point is displaying 100 notes of 100 words each at the same time is the same as displaying 1 note of 10000 words. Typically Evernote or Onenote has 3 panes design where only 1 pane displays note content. Left pane will show search results, main view area shows note content. You need to click every single item on the left pane for the main area to show note content.

A different design would have main area as the "infinite scroll" view container. It shows all notes in the left pane. If left pane selects a notebook, it shows all notes in that notebook if possible. If left pane selects a tag, the same thing. If left pane filters notes by search keywords, main area will show all notes back to back. This requires main area implemented as cells. If user clicks on a cell (that contain a note), it may expand into full area. This idea utilizes scrollbar heavily. And this unflattens note structure.

Search within filter. What I really want to have is the ability to search the main area and have the keywords highlighted. That way, I grab the scroll bar and see which cell has highest frequency of keywords. Think as Chrome with scrollbar highlight markers.

An analogy would be a PDF book with 10 chapters. I open it with PDF Xchange viewer, I would want the book to have "continuous scrolling view", to locate information, I search for "keywords", then all keywords are highlighted and locations marked on scrollbar. It would be terrible if I have to open each chapter individually to see what is in that chapter.

Comment: My TiddlyWiki seems to fit the bill..

Comment: Goldmine of information, keywords, non-linear note taking sofware: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/109/is-there-any-efficient-non-linear-note-taking-software